# Magento 2.3 Customer custom Attribute in email template

Tags: magento2.3, email-templates

I have created some custom Customer attribute and added them in Customer registration form, everything is fine, except that when a successful registration email goes I want to send those attribute values in email, I am able to send customer name in email fine using

```
$customer.name
```

and for custom attributes I tried:

```
{{var $customer.getCustomAttribute('attribute_code')}}
```

also tried this:

```
{{trans "%bname" banme=$customer.getCustomAttribute('attribute_code')}}
```

but always getting blank value.

==========================

Managed to get the values directly using

{{var customer.customattributecode}}